# Old movie or TV episode involving a girl who raced go-karts and a leprechaun or some other deity who helped her to win a race

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I've been searching for this movie off an on for what feels like 10+ years.
I'm unsure if the sole focus was go-kart racing but I know it was reoccurring in the film.

The parts I remember 100% of:

- The father switched the rear tires on the go-kart to more aggressive mud terrains for a race.
- And during the race she got help from either a leprechaun or some other deity that was able to teleport her closer to the end of the track resulting in her winning.
- She was later ridiculed for potentially cheating in the race because first place driver never saw her pass them.

That's really all I can remember. I do remember enjoying it as a kid and I'm also not sure if it was from a TV show or a movie. In which way I remember the style, it comes to me that it was a movie.

If someone could help that would be incredible. I've sent this message to other movie help websites but never got a single reply and searching go-kart movies brings up nothing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: possibly from 1990 to 2005, had to delete last message thought you asked when I saw it.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[A Very Unlucky Leprechaun](https://monsterhuntermoviereviews.com/2016/03/17/a-very-unlucky-leprechaun-1998/)* (1989)

> McGreedy wants to force Howard out of the house so that he can demolish it and build something a bit more profitable than a run down house whose owners can’t pay the taxes on. But one thing is standing in McGreedy’s way – the lucrative go kart race with a purse of 5000 pounds! Why, if Molly could somehow win that, that would almost pay for less than half what is owed! But two things are standing between her and outdoor karting immortality – McGreedy’s evil sons!

....

> Because he hasn’t eaten a four leaf clover in a long time, he’s the titular unlucky leprechaun. It shouldn’t be much of spoiler to folks well versed in unlucky leprechaun lore to know that his helping Molly during the race after the McGreedy’s used their James Bond go karts to slime her tires by flying her go-kart over part of the course totally backfired. And not just because the special effects of the flying go-kart were almost as a diabolically bad as when you could see the string holding up the magic talking starfish, but because it got her disqualified because nobody saw her at a check point! I know! Can you believe it? There was a talking starfish in the movie! That wasn’t even advertised!

### Trailer

Found with a search for `film leprechaun "go kart" -horror`, the last to screen out the eponymous *Leprechaun* films (although both star Warwick Davis!). Weirdly enough, I had already put a like on the video for the trailer, which suggests that I've searched for terms like this before, although I don't find an answer on this site which matches up with it.

Comment: In retrospect, I shouldn't be so surprised that Warwick Davis was the leprechaun... [not the first time I've mentioned one of his Leprechaun films](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168142/a-horse-that-turns-into-a-unicorn-with-a-girl-who-meets-a-leprechaun-thing/168145#168145).

Comment: im utterly shocked this was found so quickly Hats off to you and Thank you!